# Bootstrap is not working properly in different screens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootsrap3 in my app.In the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vMYKY/42/) there are 2 divs and each div is divided into 2 divs with `col-md-6` and the 2nd div is into 2 divs `col-md-3`

The 2nd div contains 2 images(each div has one image each).When the fiddle is in full width and height,there are no spaces in between the images but when the fiddle is slightly changed then spaces appears in between the images and also the 2nd div comes to right.

My requirement-- In computer pcs,I want the 1st div towards left side(div containing logo) and the 2nd div(div containing the images towards right side) but in mobiles I want all the divs(1st and 2nd to appear one after another) but this is not working.Herewith I am also attaching both the screenshots.

[image]

In the above scrrenshot,logo div is in left side and image div is right as per my requirement.

[image]

Now in the above screenshot,I have just slightly changed the borwser width and here both the divs are coming towards left side also the space between the images are increased.Where did I do the mistake.

[image]

The above picture is for mobile screens which is working fine

This is my html code

```
<div class="container">
       <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6">
                       <img src="http://www.computerhope.com/logo.gif" alt="Logo"  class="round"> user
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-6 ">Recently purchased
                       <div id="slideshow">
                               <span class="images">
                                       <div class="col-md-3"><div class="box">
                                               <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100/abstract" />
                                                       <span class="caption simple-caption">
                                                               <p>Review</p>
                                                       </span>
                                           </div></div>
                                       <div class="col-md-3"><div class="box">
                                               <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100/food" />
                                                       <span class="caption simple-caption">
                                                               <p>Review</p>
                                                       </span>
                                           </div></div>
                               </span>

                                       <a class="next" href="#">Next</a>
                       </div>
               </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to provide html markup please.

Comment: @moonwave99 Hey I have provided the fiddle so thought its not required to post the html also.I will now post the html also

Comment: @moonwave99 I have posted the html codes,Please see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to also target the smaller screen devices between mobile and medium devices.

You’ll need to define the grid sizes at this width too as I think by default Bootstrap stacks at this point.

You can do this by referencing the same grid sizes with `.col-sm-*`

For example:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
```

-EDIT-

To get required results define the xs devices too, for example:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,As you can see in the images that I have posted in this question.First image is ok for bigger screens and last image is also ok for smaller screens.I do not want like 2nd image if the screen size is altered

Comment: The `.col-sm-*` should target this screen width. Does it not work?

Comment: For this project it might be worth defining `xs` and `sm` devices then. For example: `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">` [See example](http://jsfiddle.net/vMYKY/45/)

Comment: In the fiddle you have provided there are 2 divs each having  col-xs-12,Is it possible?We have by default 12 cols in one row but you are assigining 2 divs 12 each

Comment: Feel free to test it but should work in Bootstrap 3 because as per their documentation they explain that the gutter padding is offset in rows for the first and last column via negative margin on `.row`. In earlier versions of bootstrap you would have have to work out the actual first and last column of each row.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using bootsrap3 in my app.In the fiddle there are 2 divs and each
>   div is divided into 2 divs with col-md-6 and the 2nd div is into 2
>   divs col-md-3

Below is how I would go about doing this.. Try this without rest of your css... and using only bootstrap css

```
<div class="container">


<div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="col-sm-6"> your stuff here.. if you have image use class="img-responsive" always </div>
<div class="col-sm-6"> your stuff here.. if you have image use class="img-responsive" always </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="col-sm-3"> your stuff here.. if you have image use class="img-responsive" always </div>
<div class="col-sm-3"> your stuff here.. if you have image use class="img-responsive" always </div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: Can you provide me a fiddle?